# Windows chkdsk deleted all my Linux files

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7, data-recovery, undelete

I have a dual boot setup and when I booted into windows one time chkdsk automatically ran. It ended up deleting a bunch of files on my NTFS storage HDD, all the deleted files were created on Linux. What's the best way to go about recovering the files? And how can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: What let you to your believe that Windows chkdsk deleted the files?  Did it tell you any message that it was doing something?  Or have you just been unable to find certain files afterwards and have assumed it had something to do with the chkdsk?  Do the files appear when viewed on Ubuntu?

Comment: @thomasrutter the chkdsk process said something along the lines of  "deleting index entries for x" where x was all my screenshots etc. When I went back into linux, they were gone

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't help you further, except to speculate that something corrupted your files before Windows chkdsk got to them - whether an unexpected power loss or something you did to the drive, ... I have no other ideas.

For recovery maybe try testdisk (to see if they can be undeleted) or photorec (otherwise).

You can get both from http://www.cgsecurity.org/